# Logic puzzle - All people born in Italy are citizens of EU

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

I need to choose a logically equivalent statement to the title out of the following list (A to E).

A. All EU citizens are born in Italy.

B. All non-EU citizens were not born in Italy.

C. Some non-EU citizens may have been born in Italy.

D. Those not born in Italy are not EU citizens.

E. Those born in Italy are not necessarily EU citizens.

I thought about it and I think it's D because the premise is that all people born in Italy are citizens of EU.

Is it correct?

Comment: What about the Frenchmen?

Comment: That's incorrect. Italy is a subset of the EU, not the entire EU. The error made in D is called "reversing the implication" and it's a logical fallacy. I would encourage you to forget this a logic puzzle and ask which answer makes sense in the real world.

Comment: So it's C?The other ones doesn't make sense for me

Comment: I could go with E but the premisse is that all of people born in italy is EU citizen

Comment: Think about the contrapositive of the statement that all people born in Italy are citizens of the EU.  First, write the preceding statement in the form "If __, then __ ."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gae. S. pointed out in the comments, your answer is incorrect since a person born in France is also a citizen of the European Union.

We know that all people born in Italy are citizens of the European Union.  This statement can be written as an implication:

> If a person is born in Italy, then he or she is a citizen of the European Union.

The [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of this statement is logically equivalent to it.  What is the contrapositive of the above statement?

> If a person is not a citizen of the European Union, then he or she was not born in Italy.

Now rephrase the contrapositive and compare it with the given choices.